# Photoshop question

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image][image][image]

How do you please get each one of these trees on to their own individual layers in Photoshop? They started off this way. Right now using CS4. Long story please don't ask. : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to marquee around each tree with the selection tool "M", and press Ctrl+J to copy your selected area to a new layer. You can do this to all 3 trees and remove the original bottom layer.

Comment: I believe you can also right-click the selection and make a new layer from the selection.

Comment: I did a marquee around one of my trees like you said and pressed Ctrl+ but it didn't work. I am on a Mac, does that change anything please? Also, please a completely unrelated question, but how do you check on your artboard size in Photoshop?

Comment: So now I get the first above screen shot. With the message "could not move the selection because the selected area is empty." I can now move the middle tree around but I still can't get it into it's own layer. It is independent from the other 2 trees. But where do I go from here please?

Comment: I have no idea how I got the marching ants around the middle tree, it was by a complete fluke. Now I am trying to do the same for the other 2.

Comment: Errm, I'm not sure about the artboard size, except for Image > Canvas size. But make sure to be on your original layer each time you do the Ctrl J to make a copy of the selection on a new layer.

Comment: I want to make my size the size of the first screen shot with all the trees. Also is there another way to get the marching ants around the tree? This time I used the magnetic lasso tool. But I know for certainty for the middle tree I did not. I have no idea how I got them that time?

Comment: You may want to check out some PS tutorials, as this is going to be an ongoing journey for you. They have many youtube videos and of course Lynda.com has great information!

Comment: It wasn't canvas size it was image size so I figured that one out. I also figured out the copy and paste part. It is just the selecting the object. Photoshop is not my thing. I much prefer Illustrator. If it weren't for the fact that I was using Photoshop brushes. And that I needed to remove the watermark, and the background and change the tree colour I would be in Illustrator instead. I figured out how to do all those parts myself.

Comment: And the fact that I called it artboard and not canvas should have been some indication. : )

Comment: I thought they did not have artboards in PS CS4?

Comment: I called the canvas an artboard because I use Illustrator far more than I use Photoshop. Therefore, I called it the wrong name!